How to fix auto-mounting usb drive
I have a new install of ubuntu 24.04 server. It fails to mount my usb drive when it is plugged in. I have tried a couple different ones but one is formatted on macos as fat32. /dev/sdb1 is created but it isn't mounted in /media/.
I can mount it manually using:
$:> sudo udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1
Mounted /dev/sdb1 at /media/root/5F6B-535A

Obviously I could just put this one in fstabs but what I want is more like what I understood was the "standard" behavior for ubuntu. Maybe this is only behavior of the desktop flavor but I use sticks all the time from cameras and drones. I have usb drives for certain projects and swap them in and out all the time. I'd like to have anything plugged in to be mounted immediately, not after editting fstabs.
How do I get usb drives to mount automatically when inserted? This is the behavior I'm used to with ubuntu, is this (NOT mounting drives) something peculiar to the server version?

$ sudo fdisk -l or $ lsblk -ape7 -o +MODEL,FSTYPE should have a block device (e.g. /dev/sdb) listed for your USB-drive, "automount" isn't likely to do anything without it. As I interpret your fdisk -l output you do not have that.

@Hannu tried a different usb stick and get the listing added above.

@hannu This is a little backup stick formatted FAT32 for what I though would be maximum compatibility. Is FAT32 no longer allowed in auto-mount without some config change?.

what you call "automount" is done by "udev". check what udev does while you add the stick to the system: sudo udevadm monitor and check the last lines from sudo dmesg.

@Marco it adds the "new high-speed USB device" at /dev/sbdb1 but it isn't mounted at /media/* See update above.

$ ls /media/ -> hannu  root - on my Ubuntu 24.04.  $ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sbdb1 should does mount your USB-mem, but maybe that dpkg -l |  grep -i fat should have an ii before dosfstools also.

I have dosfstools and can mount the usb drive with udisksctl but only if I do sudo su to log in as root first. I can view files on the drive as root. I know how to deal with permissions manually but would like to mount the drive or other drives automatically (using udev?) when I plug them in so my user can access them. Maybe some feature is disabled on the server version of Ubuntu?

Why not add it to /etc/fstab? Then it will mount when the computer starts.

See this Q&A and this one as well.

Thanks but I am asking why this doesn't work like "standard" ubuntu, which mounts any usb stick automatically. That is the behavior I'm looking for. I use sticks all the time from cameras and drones. I'd like to fix this to just mount whatever is plugged in, and in any combo - not just this one in this usb slot.

I read those references and neither discuss how to automatically mount any drive inserted. AFAICT you have to have an ID for the drive to use those solutions, they are not universal solutions for any drive inserted.

You can use /dev/sdX1, where X will depend on your setup instead of a specific UUID of a partition. Assuming all the USBs have one partition. If not, it will mount the first partition in your USB.

Some new info: the server distro does not have Gnome desktop and so is missing its automount solution. The docs say to use usbmount to automount but there is none in the repos. Yikes, do I need to install Gnome desktop?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB
